# How to upload image using presignedurl from aws S3 server in android

Tags: android, amazon-s3, httpurlconnection

I am trying to upload image to S3 bucket from presigned url it is giving ssl exception error connection closed by peer

here is my code

```
public int upload(String filePath, URL url) {
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos);
            byte[] fileBytes = bos.toByteArray();

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"); 

            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            output.flush();

            return connection.getResponseCode();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured it out,
here is the code to send image to S3 using presigned URL

```
try {

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileBytes);
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"); // Very important ! It won't work without adding this!

            OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();


            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, output);
            output.flush();

            int response = connection.getResponseCode();

            return connection.getResponseCode();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```